# Run .bat file as Administrator, get old version?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, cmd

This is just bizarre. I've got a .bat file that I run using Windows 7's scheduler, and I noticed after I made an update to it, that it was still acting as though it were running the old version of the .bat program.

It's easy to tell which one ran - they output to a .txt file, and the new version dumps a lot more information. So here's what happens under three scenarios:

Open a cmd window (with right-click and "Run As Administrator"). CD to the directory and execute setvispw.bat in the usual way, by typing "setvispw.bat" and hitting Enter.

Result: current version runs as expected.

Right-click setvispw.bat and "Open"

Result: current version runs as expected. But that's not good, because I'm changing another user's password and need Admin privileges.

Right-click setvispw.bat and "Run As Administrator".
Result: something else runs! It looks like it's running the version from before I made changes to the .bat just a few days ago.

So I tried something even more strange. I replaced my functional program with a dummy program... and it was running the dummy program.

Finally, I added some "pause" statements... and that's when I got the answer. Rather than discard this bit of troubleshooting, I'll use the "Answer your own darned question" feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that I was depending on the output to setvispw.bat to tell me what version of the program had run. Well, both the old and new versions had this line:

```
echo Random string is !_RndAlphaNum! > C:\pathname\curVisitorPW.txt
```

But my added line was like this:

```
echo Sending email: >> curVisitorPW.txt
```

When I ran from C:\pathname, either in a CMD window or without Admin privileges, it worked just fine. But when I ran with Admin privs, like it does from the Scheduler, the working directory isn't C:\pathname - it's C:\Windows\System32. I didn't see that until I added the "pause" and saw that I wasn't running where I expeted! Sure enough, there's a curVisitorPW.txt sitting there in System32.

The solution, of course, was simple - use the fully qualified pathname.

Hopefully this will come in handy if someone like me is seeing bizarre behavior in a .bat file, and starts wondering if there's some sort of caching, or admin permissions/privileges, or something else crazy. I was ready to pin it on gremlins, myself.